# How to Support -AsJob Parameter in Custom PowerShell Functions and Cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I've searched as far and wide as I can but I can not seem to find a method to support the `-AsJob` parameter with a custom PowerShell function or cmdlet. Ideally I'd not wrap `Start-Job` with in my code. I'd like to use whatever native solutions are available, if they exist, just as `[CmdletBinding()]` enables for `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm`.

Comment: Since `-AsJob` is not one of PowerShell's [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters), you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: However, given that you have `Start-Job` for starting arbitrary commands _locally_ as jobs, and `Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName ...` for starting arbitrary commands _remotely_, why do you need a _specific command_ to support it?

Comment: I'm looking to implement a C# based module that will invoke long running tasks (and will be used in both locally and remotely) that will return data that the end user will care about, a job is the perfect solution to this. I as hoping something standard existed for implementing them instead of having to wrap Start-Process inside the source.

Comment: Maybe someone else has a better idea, but it sounds like you'll simply have to invoke `Start-Job` inside your function and pass out the resulting background job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found some documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/how-to-support-jobs

For the C# cmdlet module:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
  if (asjob)
  {
    // Add the job definition to the job repository,
    // return the job object, and then create the thread
    // used to run the job.
    JobRepository.Add(job);
    WriteObject(job);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WorkItem);
  }
  else
  {
    job.ProcessJob();
    foreach (PSObject p in job.Output)
    {
      WriteObject(p);
    }
  }
}
```

I went and made my own JobImpl that's different from the example.  You have to make a new file PSJobImpl.cs

```
public class PSJobImpl: Job
{
    Action<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> _logicWithOutput;

    public PSJobImpl(string command, Action<PSDataCollection<PSObject>> logicWOutput) : base(command)
    {
        SetJobState(JobState.NotStarted);
        _logicWithOutput = logicWOutput;
    }
    public override string StatusMessage
    {
        get { return "Status"; }
    }

    public override bool HasMoreData
    {
        get
        {
            return hasMoreData;
        }
    }
    private bool hasMoreData = true;

    public override string Location
    {
        get { return "Location"; }
    }

    public override void StopJob()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ProcessJob()
    {
        SetJobState(JobState.Running);
        DoProcessLogic();
        SetJobState(JobState.Completed);
    }

    void DoProcessLogic()
    {
        if(_logicWithOutput != null)
        {
            _logicWithOutput(Output);
            Output.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Example invocation (from your C# cmdlet module):

```
PSJobImpl j = new PSJobImpl("CmdletName", (outputCollection) =>
{
    outputCollection.Add("[PSObject goes here]");
});
```

(Please edit my answer if you have a better implementation for StatusMessage and Location and StopJob) - I'm just sharing my code here so that others can get started with something.

Comment: Thank you so so much! You're a lifesaver! I wish I could give you more than a single vote, I had given up on this

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad you got it to work.  Thanks for letting me know that it was helpful.  The documentation on this is scarce.